How in PhpStorm to show info about current git branch?
If there is a way in PhpStorm 2024 to show info about current git branch and number of files modified in the branch, maybe in status bar?
Working with git in PhpStorm I prefer make all commands under console (just old habit), not in PhpStorm, but I would like to see info on branch I work with...
DETAILS WHAT I WANT :
The idea is that switching between branches I forget on which branch I work now.


Did you rule out using PHPStorm terminal window to use command line for git as you're used to?

where is such option ?

I guess it might vary with versions and plugins, but on my PHPStorm it's a collapsable bottom window, accessible though a ">_ Terminal" tab. I don't use it myself, I prefer having my GitBash terminal open in the background. (Edit: I just checked the settings, and "Terminal" is indeed a plugin.)

Number of files modified compared to something or? What kind of status bar do you expect?

Please read DETAILS WHAT I WANT

The VCS in use and a branch should be shown in the status bar. Please right click it and enable that widget (you must have VCS properly configured in PhpStorm itself for that). The same can also be reached via "Main Menu | View | Appearance | Status Bar Widgets" https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/guided-tour-around-the-user-interface.html#status-bar It only shows a branch, not how many lines or files modified.

If it's not there -- check the window header then. If you are using the New UI, it has moved there. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/new-ui.html#window_header -- see point #3 VCS widget. "The widget shows the current branch, allows switching branches, and provides the most popular VCS actions like update project, commit and push changes."
